# InDesign - Content going into other page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I just made myself a 18 page InDesign document to print. Then I drew Graphic Frames that line up to the page edges and placed my images (Using File > Place.. or CTRL + D) in the graphic frames.

When I later export the document to PDF, I find that almost each page has either a black line (that differs in size but no bigger than a small stroke) or the image from the next page overlaps into another.

So my question, where did I go wrong?

I checked each graphic frame I made. They are touching the middle page edge exactly. However when I double click on the placed image, the image (now a red line) is overlapping into the other page. But if it outside the graphic frame (the blue line), shouldn't it not appear?

Thank you!

Comment: I think we need to see an image of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is perhaps a tad confusing due to usage of non-common terminology. So for the sake of trying to answer, I'm going to assume:

- "files" actually means **placed images**
- "marquee box" actually means **Graphic Frame**
- "black margin line" actually means **page edge**

If these assumptions are incorrect, please click the [EDIT](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/106454/edit) link under your question and provide  more detail.

---

So.. the issue....

You've got document pages....
You've drawn a graphic frame which should line up with your page edge....
You've then used `File > Place` to place (linked) images inside the graphic frames....
When you export to PDF, you are seeing some images overlapping extra pages undesirabley.

That seems to be the issue, again, please [EDIT](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/106454/edit) and correct the question if this is not the issue.

---

All you need to do is turn on snapping (`View > Guides & Grids > Snap to Guides`) and **zoom in** on a page corner.

Then using the **Move Tool** (black arrow), click the graphic and its frame should highlight.

Ensure the edge of the **graphic frame** is indeed at the **edge of your page** by moving the frame's handle at the corner.

It's sometimes easy to over or undershoot the page edge if you aren't zoomed in. Turning on the snapping *should* make the graphic frame snap to the edge when you get close to it. And you'll want to check opposite corners.. top right and bottom left... or top left and bottom right.. for any page that has a graphic frame at it's edge.

A perhaps easier solution may be to utilize a small **[bleed](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/set-print-bleed.html)** which would allow images to slightly overlap the page edges. This is *highly* dependent upon your end output though and what the PDF is destined for. If you are setting up a PDF for commercial printing, bleeds should **always** be used if *anything* is meant to trail off the edge of a document page. Also note, that with a press-ready PDF that contains bleeds and marks, you **will** absolutely see opposite page content in a single page PDF. That's how bleeds work. I honestly don't know if this may be what you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks @Scott! Sorry I wrote that at nearly 4am, brain half dead, mid panic because I needed it for the next day and you can probably guess how that all turned out. I'll make the corrections, but you got what I meant perfectly. Thank you for your help, I managed to sort out the issue and I think what I just saw in the PDF as well was the small bleed. I can't be certain anymore. I apologise again for my over dramatic panic. Oh god, can I be embarrassing or what? xD I hope my *corrected* question looks proper now thanks to your corrections.